# FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have multiple activities that manage a connection (**B** => **C** => **D**).  If that connection drops out, they should all clear out and return a result back to **A**, depending on the reason (`RESULT_USER_TERMINATED, RESULT_LOW_SIGNAL, RESULT_UNKOWN`, etc...)

### In A I have

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_EXIT_STATUS);
```

### In B & C

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, C.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

### IN D

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
setResult(ConnectActivity.RESULT_USER_TERMINATED);
startActivity(intent);
```

This does not work. Instead, **A** gets `RESULT_CANCELED`.  How can I make this work as expected?  Alternatively, is there a better way to acheive the same result?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest passing the result back down the stack instead of making use of `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT`, such that each new Activity B, C, D are started for result and each Activity implemented onActivityResult and simply forwards the result down eg:

```
@Override protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    setResult(resultCode);
    finish();
}
```

That way the intended result code will make it's way back to your Activity A regardless of which Activity (B, C, D) generated it.